# Find row where value is reached again

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this:

```
+-----+----+----+--------+
|index|name| Num|solution|
+-----+----+----+--------+
|    0|   a|1000|    true|
|    1|   a|2000|    true|
|    2|   a| 300|   false|
|    3|   a| 400|    true|
|    4|   a|2100|    true|
|    5|   a|2200|    true|
+-----+----+----+--------+
```

I now want to update my solution column. If the value (`Num`) before the "drop"(here the Value before the drop would be 2000) is reached or surpassed FOR THE FIRST time again, I want to set all Bools to False from "drop" on until after that point. So expected outcome would be:

```
+-----+----+----+---------------+
|index|name| Num|solution_update|
+-----+----+----+---------------+
|    0|   a|1000|           true|
|    1|   a|2000|           true|
|    2|   a| 300|          false|
|    3|   a| 400|          false|
|    4|   a|2100|          false|
|    5|   a|2200|           true|
+-----+----+----+---------------+
```

I feel like I am missing the general idea on how to solve this :-\

I can detect the value in the row before drop with:

```
my_window = Window.partitionBy('name').orderBy(F.col('index'))

df= df.withColumn('lag1', F.lag(F.col('Num'), -1)
                    .over(my_window).cast('bigint'))
df= df.withColumn('help',
                        (F.when((F.col('lag1'))
                                    < (F.col('Num')), False)))
+-----+----+----+--------+----+-----+
|index|name| Num|solution|lag1| help|
+-----+----+----+--------+----+-----+
|    0|   a|1000|    true|2000| null|
|    1|   a|2000|    true| 300|false|
|    2|   a| 300|   false| 400| null|
|    3|   a| 400|    true|2100| null|
|    4|   a|2100|    true|2200| null|
|    5|   a|2200|    true|null| null|
+-----+----+----+--------+----+-----+
```

But now I got no clue how I can search for "first value equal or greater" than

```
df.where(F.col('help')==False)['Num']
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an easy one. Here's how I would go about it. Hopefully the columns are self-explanatory enough :) but do ask if you are unclear about the meaning of any column.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

my_window = Window.partitionBy('name').orderBy(F.col('index'))

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'drop',
    F.when(F.col('Num') < F.lag('Num').over(my_window), F.lag('Num').over(my_window))
).withColumn(
    'num_before_drop',
    F.last('drop', ignorenulls=True).over(my_window)
).withColumn(
    'surpass',
    F.col('Num') > F.col('num_before_drop')
).withColumn(
    'first_surpass',
    F.col('surpass') & ~F.lag('surpass').over(my_window)
).withColumn(
    'solution_update',
    F.when(~F.col('surpass') | F.col('first_surpass'), F.lit(False))
     .otherwise(F.col('solution'))
)

df2.show()
+-----+----+----+--------+----+---------------+-------+-------------+---------------+
|index|name| Num|solution|drop|num_before_drop|surpass|first_surpass|solution_update|
+-----+----+----+--------+----+---------------+-------+-------------+---------------+
|    0|   a|1000|    true|null|           null|   null|         null|           true|
|    1|   a|2000|    true|null|           null|   null|         null|           true|
|    2|   a| 300|   false|2000|           2000|  false|        false|          false|
|    3|   a| 400|    true|null|           2000|  false|        false|          false|
|    4|   a|2100|    true|null|           2000|   true|         true|          false|
|    5|   a|2200|    true|null|           2000|   true|        false|           true|
+-----+----+----+--------+----+---------------+-------+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Ah, great! At least I am happy that it wasn't an all easy solution :O)
You're right, column names are self-explanatory, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

win = Window.partitionBy('name').orderBy('index')


# Get "largest so far"
df = df.withColumn('max_num', F.max('Num').over(win))
df = df.withColumn('running_max', F.expr('max_num > Num'))

# Now lag the largest so far and form a combined indicator
df = df.withColumn('lag_running_max', F.lag('running_max').over(win)).na.fill(False)
df =  df.withColumn('combined_indicator', F.expr("running_max or lag_running_max"))

# update solution column
df = df.withColumn('updated_solution', F.when(F.col("combined_indicator"), False).otherwise(F.col("solution")))
```

Comment: Your solution works as well, thanks :) Still, I don't really get what 
F.expr("running_max or lag_running_max=1")
does. It checks if running_max is true or lag_running_max is false? But that doesn't make sense in that case. Can you shortly explain? :)

Comment: so that `=1` bit was a typo / redundant. I have removed it (and the code still works).

Comment: and what it does is basically the reason for having that line is that you want the flag to switch to true only *after* the running max is exceeded (hence the need to lead the running max exceeded indicator and logical or that with the "un-led" value).

Comment: hope that clarifies